# App crashing in iOS 8 while opening popover working in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios8

The popover is crashing the application while I am working with iOS 8.
This is the code that I have written and it is in the method when the user selects the popover:

```
- (IBAction) onSelectingDefect:(id)sender
    {
        if ([description isFirstResponder]) {
            [self hideKeyBoard];
            return;
        }

        UIButton *button = (UIButton*)(sender);
        UIButton *doneSelectingStatusButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        doneSelectingStatusButton.frame = CGRectMake(85, 223, 149, 32);
        [doneSelectingStatusButton setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [doneSelectingStatusButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [doneSelectingStatusButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [doneSelectingStatusButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel_button02.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [doneSelectingStatusButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onPickerSelection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
        pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        pickerView.delegate = self;
        pickerView.dataSource = self;
        BOOL isNill = TRUE;
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<[tableData count]; i++)
        {
            if([selectedPickerText isEqualToString:[tableData objectAtIndex:i]])
            {
                isNill = FALSE;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isNill)
        {
            [pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES]; //Orig
            //self.selectedPickerText = [tableData objectAtIndex:0];
            self.selectedPickerText = [tableData objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        else
            [pickerView selectRow:i inComponent:0 animated:YES];//Orig

        UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 255)];
        [containerView addSubview:doneSelectingStatusButton];
        [containerView addSubview:pickerView];

        UIViewController *pickerViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        CGRect myRect = button.frame;
        myRect.origin.x += 10;
        myRect.origin.y += 10;

        selectionPopover  = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerViewController];
        ((AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).secondPopOver = selectionPopover;
        selectionPopover.delegate =self;
        selectionPopover.popoverContentSize  = CGSizeMake(320, 255);
        [selectionPopover presentPopoverFromRect:selectDefect.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; //Error iOS8
        pickerViewController.view = containerView;

        [containerView release];
        [pickerView release];
        [pickerViewController release];
    }
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
2014-11-04 20:01:30.740 Service360[447:5288] -[UITextField length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f0d6520
2014-11-04 20:01:30.743 Service360[447:5288] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f0d6520'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0321f946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02d01a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x032275c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x031703e7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0316ffae _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x03108d26 CFStringAppend + 374
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0310684a __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 11754
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x031fc5f5 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 245
    8   Foundation                          0x028b7697 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 159
    9   Foundation                          0x028baf42 +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 89
    10  UIKit                               0x0183dd34 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 2825
    11  UIKit                               0x018405d2 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 345
    12  UIKit                               0x01840424 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 224
    13  UIKit                               0x01db0791 -[UIPopoverController _presentShimmedPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:] + 217
    14  UIKit                               0x01db0991 -[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:] + 355
    15  Service360                          0x00369b52 -[POVendorFeedbackViewController onSelectingDefect:] + 2770
    16  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02d177cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    17  UIKit                               0x016da23d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
    18  UIKit                               0x016da1cf -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
    19  UIKit                               0x0180de86 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69
    20  UIKit                               0x0180e2a3 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598
    21  UIKit                               0x0180d50d -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 660
    22  UIKit                               0x0172a60a -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
    23  UIKit                               0x0172b0e5 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 791
    24  UIKit                               0x016f0549 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    25  Service360                          0x00068f22 -[MyApplication sendEvent:] + 178
    26  UIKit                               0x0170037e _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20690
    27  UIKit                               0x016d4b19 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x031431df __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x03138ced __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x03138248 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x03137bcb CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x031379fb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    33  GraphicsServices                    0x044b424f GSEventRunModal + 192
    34  GraphicsServices                    0x044b408c GSEventRun + 104
    35  UIKit                               0x016d88b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    36  Service360                          0x0006793f main + 159
    37  libdyld.dylib                       0x077a7ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The line which is causing the app to crash is:

```
[selectionPopover presentPopoverFromRect:selectDefect.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; //Error iOS8
```

What can be the issue which is causing this error. The app works fine in earlier or previous releases of iOS.

Comment: How is `selectionPopover` defined?  (Try making it a `strong` property and using `self.selectionPopover` to reference it.)

Comment: as per error you are accessing textfield length. but textfield is not exist. `-[UITextField length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f0d6520`

Comment: @Philip: Selection popover is UIView Controller,  UIPopoverController *selectionPopover;

Comment: I suggest using the "strong property" approach to see whether there's a memory management answer.

Comment: @PhillipMills: Tried this ...
`@property(strong , nonatomic) UIPopoverController *selectionPopover   
@synthesize selectionPopover;
[self.selectionPopover presentPopoverFromRect:selectDefect.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; //Error iOS8`

Comment: Same error...any other way to go about this...

Comment: Exactly similar code working on other screens... the addition here is 
`UIViewController *pickerViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    CGRect myRect = button.frame;
    myRect.origin.x += 10;
    myRect.origin.y += 10;`

Can this be causing issues?

Comment: Maybe turn on zombies in your build scheme and see if it gives you a better error message.  Or, run with Instruments and trace the life cycle of the instance address that it complains about.

Comment: Zombie already enabled...

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you are getting length of a textfield. The textfield does not exist or you are getting in the wrong way. The correct way is **[textfield.text length]** instead of **[textfield length]**.

Comment: These are the only 2 places where I am using Textfield and I am using [textfield.text length]

Comment: - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

Comment: Just to clarify:

NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

Comment: `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSRange newRange = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[MasterBL sharedInstance] getDisallowedCharacterSet]];
    if(newRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    if(textField == description && newLength > 80)
        return NO;
    return YES;
}`

Comment: `IBOutlet UITextField *description`

Comment: and what is [[MasterBL sharedInstance]?

Comment: Look for a stringWithFormat somewhere in your loading code of the viewController you're presenting.  You're calling length on something in there that's bringing it down.

Comment: @OwenHartnett: I am not calling length except for the code mentioned above. There are some methods that are just checking if it is null or not... stringWithFormat is also not used. :(